# Why doesn't this .desktop script launch the program?

Tags: 12.04, unity, wine, scripts

The following script creates an icon in Dash Home, but doesn't launch the program. Any ideas why not?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Civ 5
Comment=Civ & 5
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/mark/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Sid Meier's Civilization V; wine CivilizationV.exe"
Icon=wine
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Exec` field should be:

```
wine "/home/mark/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Sid Meier's Civilization V/CivilizationV.exe"
```

Yours fail because the path to the executable contains spaces and `sh` fails to `cd` there.